# c# identifier not found

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace it2b_project_01
{
    static class class1
    {
        static public class1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public static void error_check(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

(different .cs file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace it2b_project_01
{
    public partial class Create_an_Order : Form
    {
        public Create_an_Order()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Create_an_Order_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Order_Button_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            class1.error_check();
        }
    }
}
```

Create an Order.cs(26,13): error CS0103: The name 'class1' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Is this actually compileable? I cannot find `class1.InitializeComponent` in the code.

Answer (score 1):

make

```
static class class1

public static class class1
```

it cannot find it because it is not public

Comment: same error?  you also need to pass parameters to the function --- class1.error_check(sender, e);

Comment: class1 not found. I get a blue line under class1.

Comment: remove public from the class1 constructor

Comment: doesn't work for me JDMX

        static class1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Someone tell me the exact procedure how you did it including how you added the .cs file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Access modifiers like public are not allowed on static constructors so drop the public from the class1 constructor.
2. error check takes 2 paramters which your not passing in.

I did those two things and it complied.

Comment: static class1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 public static void error_check(object sender, EventArgs e)


I made the changes, still the same.

Comment: yes - i.e. the Class1.cs file opens as well when I click on .sln file (Visual Studio)

Comment: There can be multiple projects inside of one sln file

Comment: @mt12: **The class file opening when you open the solution does not logically imply that the class file is a part of any project in the solution**. All that means that *you had the class file opened in the editor when you last saved the solution*. If you never added it to any project then *it's not actually being compiled*. Right-click on the project and select "Add existing item".